# Android: Drawing Text on Canvas overlaps

Tags: android, text, android-canvas, draw

I am trying to draw several Text objects onto my canvas however my text got overlapped on the canvas.

My codes are as follows:

```
  for (RectF rec : rects) {
        for(String name : nameArr){
        if (rec.height() != 50 ) {
            canvas.drawOval(rec, paintColor);
            canvas.drawText(name, x, y, paint);

        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(rec, paintColor);
            canvas.drawText(name,x,y, paint);
        }

for (String text : name) {

            canvas.drawText(text, x, y, fontpaint);

        }
```

The X and Y are from my touch coordinates every time when I touch the canvas, the text object should be drawn on the canvas. Also how can i move those text objects around the canvas? by redrawing them? Please advice thank you.

image of my output: http://postimg.org/image/3y39kt0cb/
rect 1 shld remain at the first rect on the left but it overlapped with the second one.

Comment: can you post your more of your codes. to see whats happening and where did you miss something

Comment: Looks like your loop runs over all strings and draws all of them in the same x and y coordinates

Comment: @steven0529 The text suppose to stay below the rectangles. I have added more codes above. No idea why this wont work.

Comment: @steven0529 and my output image.

Comment: why are you still looping the name array?

Comment: what is the use of the rec.height() != 50 condition?

Comment: @steven0529 because i have two types of rectangle. I need the name for the rectangles.

Comment: and the != condition?

Comment: @steven0529 thats for the specify of the rectangle. if rectangle height is not more than 50 i choose to draw it as a oval.

Comment: have you found any solution @user3306996